# Amazon MWS API : stack order of _POST_PRODUCT_DATA_

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I was wondering if I could stack _POST_PRODUCT_DATA_ feedtype to Amazon like pricing ?

I tried it and Amazon failed to recognize the second product (the first one is ok, used the same Marketplace and same seller)

I'm trying to add multiple products to Amazon. Right now it's working fine with less than 50 products per hour.

How could I get the exact limit for such feeds ?
I know that  the SubmitFeed operation has a maximum request quota of 15 and a restore rate of a request every 2 minutes.

But for instance, can't I send in one feed 10 products or more ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no limit on the number of products you send in one feed, but the size of the feed is limited to 2,147,483,647 bytes. For best performance, Amazon recommends keeping the feed size under 10MB. http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_SubmitFeed.html

If one of your products failed to update then you can usually find out why by calling `GetFeedSubmissionResult` (part of the Feeds API).

**Edit:** Here is an example `_POST_PRODUCT_DATA_` feed with multiple products. The messages are derived from examples in the [Selling on Amazon Guide to XML](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/XML_Documentation_Intl._V353515335_.pdf).

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>M_SELLER_354577</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
    <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
        <Product>
            <SKU>1Z-500ABR-FLAT</SKU>
            <StandardProductID>
                <Type>ASIN</Type>
                <Value>0123456789</Value>
            </StandardProductID>
            <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_TAX</ProductTaxCode>
            <LaunchDate>2005-07-26T00:00:01</LaunchDate>
            <DescriptionData>
                <Title>Lyric 500 tc Queen Flat Sheet, Ivory</Title>
                <Brand>Peacock Alley</Brand>
                <Description>Lyric sheeting by Peacock Alley is the epitome of simple and classic elegance. The flat sheets
                    and pillowcases feature a double row of hemstitching. The fitted sheets fit mattresses up to 21 inches deep.
                    The sheets are shown at left with tone on tone monogramming, please call for monogramming details and prices.</Description>
                <BulletPoint>made in Italy</BulletPoint>
                <BulletPoint>500 thread count</BulletPoint>
                <BulletPoint>plain weave (percale)</BulletPoint>
                <BulletPoint>100% Egyptian cotton</BulletPoint>
                <Manufacturer>Peacock Alley</Manufacturer>
                <SearchTerms>bedding</SearchTerms>
                <SearchTerms>Sheets</SearchTerms>
                <ItemType>flat-sheets</ItemType>
                <IsGiftWrapAvailable>false</IsGiftWrapAvailable>
                <IsGiftMessageAvailable>false</IsGiftMessageAvailable>
            </DescriptionData>
            <ProductData>
                <Home>
                    <Material>cotton</Material>
                    <ThreadCount>500</ThreadCount>
                </Home>
            </ProductData>
        </Product>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>2</MessageID>
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
        <Product>
            <SKU>56789</SKU>
            <StandardProductID>
                <Type>ASIN</Type>
                <Value>B0EXAMPLEG</Value>
            </StandardProductID>
            <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_NOTAX</ProductTaxCode>
            <DescriptionData>
                <Title>Example Product Title</Title>
                <Brand>Example Product Brand</Brand>
                <Description>This is an example product description.</Description>
                <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 1</BulletPoint>
                <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 2</BulletPoint>
                <MSRP currency="USD">25.19</MSRP>
                <Manufacturer>Example Product Manufacturer</Manufacturer>
                <ItemType>example-item-type</ItemType>
            </DescriptionData>
            <ProductData>
                <Health>
                    <ProductType>
                        <HealthMisc>
                            <Ingredients>Example Ingredients</Ingredients>
                            <Directions>Example Directions</Directions>
                        </HealthMisc>
                    </ProductType>
                </Health>
            </ProductData>
        </Product>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Comment: Ok then could you show me a feed (xml flat file) with at least 2 product in it ? I tried it and failed it didnt recognize the second product. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Sure, I just posted an example with messages from the SoA XML Guide.